# Getting a undefined method `validates_presence_of' for for a custom attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activemodel

I think the trouble is coming from the fact this is a custom Model.

**Error:**

```
undefined method `validates_presence_of' for Calculation:Class
```

**My Model:**

```
class Calculation
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  attr_accessor :name, :docket_num, :payments, :our_file_num,
                :date_awarded, :date_paid, :amount_paid, :judgement_balance,
                :results, :total_interest, :per_diem, :lda

  validates_presence_of :date_awarded, :docket_num, :judgement_balance
```

Possibly there is something I need to include or extend to get Rails validations? The project is within a rails project, but I constructed the model by hand.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try including `ActiveModel::Validations`.

For more info checkout the [documentation on it](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html)